Mask R-CNN: How to infer the shape of Lambda's output?
I am exploring the following sample code of Mask R-CNN:
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/tree/master/samples
However, when I ran the demo.ipynb file, an error was returned for the code below, which I don't know how to fix.
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)
The error reads as follows.
NotImplementedError: Exception encountered when calling Lambda.call().
We could not automatically infer the shape of the Lambda's output. Please specify the `output_shape` argument for this Lambda layer.
Arguments received by Lambda.call():
• args=('\<KerasTensor shape=(None, 1000, 1, 1, 1024), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_3553\>',)
• kwargs={'mask': 'None'}

It seems that the fpn_classifier_graph function caused an error as it could not identify Lambda's output, and it is necessary to specify the correct output_shape.
However, I have no idea how to modify the code...
ChatGPT suggested revising the Lambda to explicitly specify the output_shape as follows, which did not work...
shared = KL.Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(K.squeeze(x, 3), 2),
                   name="pool_squeeze",
                   output_shape=lambda s: (s[0], s[1], s[3]))(x)


Had the same issue. Rolling back keras to 2.9.0 and tensorflow to 2.9.1 fixed it for me.

I encountered same error, I changed it to use ops instead of K, it solved me that I don't have to specify the output_shape:
from keras.api.layers import Lambda, Dense, Input
from keras.api.models import Model
from keras import ops
from keras.api import backend as K
from keras.api.utils import plot_model

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))

shared_layer = Dense(1)(input_layer)

output1_layer = Dense(1)(shared_layer)

output2_stopgrad_layer = Lambda(lambda x: ops.stop_gradient(x))(shared_layer)
# output2_stopgrad_layer = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(shared_layer) # Using K returns error: We could not automatically infer the shape of the Lambda's output. Please specify the `output_shape` argument for this Lambda layer.

output2_layer = Dense(1)(output2_stopgrad_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output1_layer, output2_layer])

plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)


So, for your case, perhaps you need to change K.squeeze into ops.squeeze.
